# changing the color of a fragment on a button click

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which main `Activity` has three `buttons` red, green and blue and a `fragment` too. On clicking the `button` the color of the `fragment` changes to the respective colors of the `button`. I tried changing the `background color` of the `fragment`onclick` but my app crashes

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b1,b2,b3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            fragment1.rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            fragment1.rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    });
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    fragment1.rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
   }
  });
    }


    }
```

**Logcat:**

```
01-17 13:27:02.976 17105-17105/com.example.shivadeeps.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.shivadeeps.myapplication, PID: 17105
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.shivadeeps.myapplication.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5246)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10565)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21200)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

**fragment**

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment {
  public static View rootView;

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Where is `fragment1` ?

Comment: and also fragment1

Comment: where did you added the fragment?
fragment1 is which object ? not initialized in code itself ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity,

Set Fragment's `android:background` to transparent in `#AARRGGBB` format in XML layout. i.e.

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

and, in your `onClick()` events on MainActivity, just change the background color of layout containing fragments. i.e. in MainActivity

```
findViewById(R.id.root_layout).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

here `root_layout` is the top-root-level layout of MainActivity. You can select a layout which contains Fragments for effect in required positions.

In this method, you don't have do anything with fragments.

Comment: THANK YOU IT WORKED

Comment: i selected it just now

Answer (score 0):

you can find fragment by tag and set color of root view

```
 Fragment fragmentManager = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment1");
        if (fragmentManager != null) {
            fragmentManager.getView().getRootView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer:

```
package com.example.shivadeeps.myapplication;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import static android.R.attr.fragment;

public class fragment1 extends Fragment {
public static View rootView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
return rootView;
}
}
```